# How to add title in the is the ListView in android

Tags: android

How     to   add   title   in the   is  the  ListView   in android.

Means

### Subject         From    <--------Title

hiiiii     |    Raj     <--------List Content
hello      |    srss

Here I  have  used

EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter .

Answer (score 9):

Try **addHeaderview** in **ListView** [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using the xml layout file for list, then in that xml file use a `TextView` before the `ListView`.Its very simple.